# clearing cloudflare cache programmatically

Tags: node.js, api, callback, cloudflare, purge

I am trying to clear the cloudflare cache for single urls programmatically after put requests to a node.js api. I am using the https://github.com/cloudflare/node-cloudflare library, however I can't figure out how to log a callback from cloudflare. According to the test file in the same repo, the syntax should be something like this:

```
//client declaration:

    t.context.cf = new CF({
        key: 'deadbeef',
        email: 'cloudflare@example.com',
        h2: false
      });

//invoke clearCache:

           t.context.cf.deleteCache('1', {
            files: [
              'https://example.com/purge_url'
            ]
          })
```

How can I read out the callback from this request?
I have tried the following in my own code:

```
client.deleteCache(process.env.CLOUDFLARE_ZONE, { "files": [url] }, function (data) {
    console.log(`Cloudflare cache purged for: ${url}`);
    console.log(`Callback:${data}`);
})
```

and:

```
client.deleteCache('1', {
    files: [
        'https://example.com/purge_url'
    ]
}).then(function(a,b){
    console.log('helllllllooooooooo');
})
```

to no avail. :(

Answer (score 6):

Purging Cloudflare cache by url:

```
var Cloudflare = require('cloudflare');

const { CF_EMAIL, CF_KEY, CF_ZONE } = process.env;

if (!CF_ZONE || !CF_EMAIL || !CF_KEY) {
  throw new Error('you must provide env. variables: [CF_ZONE, CF_EMAIL, CF_KEY]');
}
const client = new Cloudflare({email: CF_EMAIL, key: CF_KEY});
const targetUrl = `https://example.com/purge_url`;

client.zones.purgeCache(CF_ZONE, { "files": [targetUrl] }).then(function (data) {
  console.log(`Cloudflare cache purged for: ${targetUrl}`);
  console.log(`Callback:`, data);
}, function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

You can lookup cloudflare zone this way:

```
client.zones.browse().then(function (zones) {
  console.log(zones);
})
```

Don't forget to install the current client version:

```
npm i cloudflare@^2.4.1 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a nodejs module to purge cache for a entire website. It scan your "public" folder, build the full url and purge it on cloudflare:

You can run it using npx:

```
npm install -g npx

npx purge-cloudflare-cache your@email.com your_cloudflare_key the_domain_zone https://your.website.com your/public/folder
```

But, you can install it and run using npm too:

```
npm install -g purge-cloudflare-cache

purge your@email.com your_cloudflare_key the_domain_zone https://your.website.com your/public/folder
```

For a public/folder tree like:

```
├── assets
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── roboto-regular.ttf
│   │   └── roboto.scss
│   ├── icon
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   └── imgs
│       └── logo.png
├── build
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── main.js
├── index.html
```

It will purge cache for files:

```
https://your.website.com/index.html
https://your.website.com/build/main.css
https://your.website.com/build/main.js
https://your.website.com/assets/imgs/logo.png
https://your.website.com/assets/icon/favicon.ico
https://your.website.com/assets/fonts/roboto.css
https://your.website.com/assets/fonts/roboto-regular.ttf
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because my mocha tests don't wait for the callback to return.

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/362